# Можно ли кастомизировать кнопку facebook "Like" и отключить блок с превью открывающийся после лайка?

Tags: facebook, like, facebooksdk

Закастомить кнопку, как я понял, нельзя. Но можно ли хотя бы как-то отключить этот блок или скрыть его? 
overflow: hidden не предлагать т.к. остается маленький белый треугольник на кнопке.

[image]

Comment: Можно, но так делать нельзя, т.к. это будет противоречить их правилам. Правда, этим вроде многие пренебрегают, но все же...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но я не разрешения спрашивал, а способ, которым можно это сделать)

Comment: [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins) п.13.4: *Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins*. Это запрещено их политикой, а значит является незаконным. Вам за это может быть бан. А нам не следует нарушать чужие правила

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Кнопку кастомизировать нельзя**.
Не разрешается никаким образом влиять на отображение кнопки "like" или менять её поведение.

> [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins) п.13.4: Don’t obscure or cover elements of social
>   plugins. Это запрещено их политикой, а значит является незаконным. Вам
>   за это может быть бан.